# F-droid: keep partial downloads

Tags: downloading, f-droid

I am trying to install OSMAnd~ which is 43 MB, but I am sitting on a crappy connection that cuts out after 10-20 MB. Can I somehow ask F-droid to keep the partially downloaded file and continue download?

Comment: You could visit their website, and download the APK using a browser/download-manager supporting resume.

Answer (score 0):

I know that f-droid at least has a long timeout before cancelling the download but as @Izzy commented above, just download the apk from:

[OSMand page](https://f-droid.org/packages/net.osmand.plus/)

[OSMAnd APK Version 2.8.2 (282) - Added on 2017-11-17](https://f-droid.org/repo/net.osmand.plus_282.apk)